# JPA No transaction is currently active

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Using JPA with EclipseLink implementation.

**Code:**

```
try{
    if(!em.getTransaction().isActive())
        em.getTransaction().begin(); 
    System.out.println(2);
    em.persist(currentUser);
    System.out.println(3);
    if (em.getTransaction().isActive()){
        System.out.println("IS ACTIVE");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NO ACTIVE");
    }
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    System.out.println(4);
    } catch (Exception e){
    completed = false;
    em.getTransaction().rollback();
    System.out.println("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

**Error:**

```
INFO: persistOne - Enter
INFO: 2
INFO: 3
INFO: IS ACTIVE
INFO: [EL Warning]: 2012-01-06 14:45:59.221--UnitOfWork(12492659)--java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: com.maze.model.UserDetail@d52ea.

WARNING: #{accountController.performRegister}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
javax.faces.FacesException: #{accountController.performRegister}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.rollback(EntityTransactionImpl.java:122)
    at com.maze.service.UserService.persistOne(UserService.java:63)
    at com.maze.controller.request.AccountController.performRegister(AccountController.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 33 more
```

The weird thing is that the Transaction is active but the next thing happening is an error of inactivity.

**EDIT**
*EntityManager Singleton:*
        public class EntityManagerSingleton {

```
private EntityManagerSingleton(){
}

private static class EMSingletonHolder{
    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Maze");
    private static final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
}

public static EntityManager getInstance(){
    return EMSingletonHolder.em;
}
```

*Getting the em Instance: *

```
public abstract class AbstractService {
protected EntityManager em;

public AbstractService(){
    em = EntityManagerSingleton.getInstance();
}
}
```

All other services extends the AbstractService

Comment: I would pay attention to this - `During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST`.

Comment: You can find my solution [at this address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50740809/418599).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging by your log, you are using GlassFish. I assume you are also using JTA.  Maybe you can provide also the code that obtains the EntityManager instance? Also, debugging with System.out statements is something from the past, use a debugger, otherwise your code is hard to read. In addition, your indentation is wrong.

First of all, if you are using JTA, take a look at this question:

[EJBException when calling entityManager.getTransaction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451846/ejbexception-when-calling-entitymanager-gettransaction)

Quote from the accepted answer:

> **It is illegal to obtain a reference to the EntityTransaction instance associated with the EntityManager in a Java EE managed context**. From
>   the Java EE API documentation of EntityManager.getTransaction():
>
> Return the resource-level EntityTransaction object. The
>   EntityTransaction instance may be used serially to begin and commit
>   multiple transactions.

```
Returns:
    EntityTransaction instance  Throws:
    IllegalStateException - if invoked on a JTA entity manager
```

That is why if you expect any help it is important to provide information about the code/injection through which you obtain the entity manager.

Also, for the sake of code readability, you should not have multiple calls to em.getTransaction();
You should assign your first call to a Transaction object and reuse it, kinda like this:

```
//GOOD cause readable
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
em.persist(someObject);
tx.commit();
```

and not

```
 //BAD cause hard to read
 em.getTransaction().begin();
 em.persist(someObject);
 em.getTransaction().commit(); //NO!
```

Comment: I'm using resource_local not JTA

Comment: The last point of your post seems to be wrong in context of resource-local entity managers. There is no reason why not calling getTransaction multiple times to get the current transaction. The EntityManager is single threaded and the spec explicitly shows an example that does it this way.

Comment: @chromanoid I was meaning it terms of code readability. Consider you need to persist 4 more objects. Would you call 'em.getTransaction().persist(someObject)' 4 more times?  Or would you prefer 'tx.persist(someObject)'? In the first approach each of the lines would read as doing 2 actions: get the transaction, persist the object.  While in fact what you want to say is 'persist the object'.

Comment: @baba the transaction is part of the EntityManager and you persist with the EntityManager not with the Transaction.
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(obj1);
em.persist(obj2);
em.getTransaction().commit();

Comment: @chromanoid regardless, if in code you have rollback or some stuff like that, it looks far cleaner to have the transaction instance once instead of doing the em.getTransaction().X. It is far more readable and suggests that we are calling the transaction, and not the em. I stand by what I said, it is far better in terms of readability to assign the transaction to something, and then reuse it, even if we are talking about two reusages. The OP's code is a clear example of how things shouldn't look and apart from formatting and other stuff, it would benefit if made in the way I suggested.

Comment: @baba Your answer suggests it would be more than readability that you sacrifice when using the "BAD" way and this is simply wrong. When using your "GOOD" way you should at least declare tx final...

Answer (score 11):

Note that the last exception is thrown by `rollback()` in the catch block.

So, `commit()` throws the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: com.maze.model.UserDetail@d52ea.

That exception causes an implicit rollback, so that the manual `rollback()` in the catch block throws another exception due to inactive transaction.

For reliable manual cleanup you need to check whether transaction is active before calling `rollback()` in the catch block as well.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your logs explain, during commit, Eclipselink got an exception and rollback your transaction. That is why your transation is no longer active..

> INFO: [EL Warning]: 2012-01-06
>   14:45:59.221--UnitOfWork(12492659)--java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship
>   that was not marked cascade PERSIST: com.maze.model.UserDetail@d52ea.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the last of these stack traces, I see

```
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.rollback(EntityTransactionImpl.java:122)
```

It's an error during rollback, not during commit. I'm wondering if this is related to the warning about the nonpersisted object; something goes wrong at the end of the commit such that your framework attempts a rollback at a point where it's too late to do so. I bet if you correctly registered that `UserDetail` object, the problem would clear up.