# Hibernate JPA Transaction not active error while running TestCases but works fine when executed in main Class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dependency-injection, transactions, guice

I am trying to insert A Entity Object in Hibernate using jpa persistence along with Guice injection via EntityManager.
It works fine when i tried to insert an object using my main class that oject entry reflects in my db.
But when i execute my  Junit testCases it shows me error : "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active " while insertion in db Remaining methods works proplerly.

```
============== AbstractHibernateRepository<T>  Class==================
@Inject
private EntityManager em;


public AbstractHibernateRepository(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return this.em;
}



@Transactional
    public T create(T entity) {
        EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
        if (!entityManager.getTransaction().isActive())
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        try {
            entityManager.persist(entity);
            if (entityManager.getTransaction().isActive()){
                entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

            }
            else
                entityManager.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("======>>>>>");
            if (entityManager.getTransaction().isActive())
                entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return entity;
    }
================================
==================  AvailableServerRepository.class ==============
public class AvailableServerRepository extends
    AbstractHibernateRepository<AvailableServerEntity> implements
    IAvailableServerRepository {

@Override
public AvailableServerEntity insertAvailableServer(
        AvailableServerEntity availableServer) {
    return create(availableServer);

}

}

====================================

public class AvailableServerRepositoryTest {
private static Injector injector = null;
private static PersistenceInitializer initializer = null;

@BeforeClass
public static void environmentSetup() {
    injector = Guice.createInjector(new MainModule(), new JpaPersistModule(
            "proplet-indexer"));
    initializer = injector.getInstance(PersistenceInitializer.class);
    initializer.startServer();
}

@AfterClass
public static void environmentClean() {
    if(initializer != null)
    initializer.stopServer();
}


/**
 * Test of insertAvailableServer method, of class AvailableServerRepository.
 */
@Test
public void testInsertAvailableServer() {
    AvailableServerRepository availableServerRepository = injector
            .getInstance(AvailableServerRepository.class);
    AvailableServerEntity availableServer = createAvailableServer();
                     assertNotNull(availableServerRepository.insertAvailableServer(availableServer));
}

====================================




Error while it throws while running testCases is 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:70)
at com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.invoke(JpaLocalTxnInterceptor.java:87)
at com.exzeo.indexer.persistence.repository.impl.AvailableServerRepository.insertAvailableServer(AvailableServerRepository.java:34)
at com.exzeo.indexer.persistence.repository.impl.AvailableServerRepositoryTest.testInsertAvailableServer(AvailableServerRepositoryTest.java:56)
```

Comment: post complete stacktrace

Comment: Hey Chaitanya it shows only this message while executing test case

Comment: You can find my solution [at this address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50740809/418599).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i found the error it is import issue.
Instead of using    javax.transaction.Transactional 
i was using    com.google.inject.persist.Transactional

So when we use google.inject.persist.transaction then the transaction was not active.Then it would through exception when someone tries to commit or flush any transaction.