# Error: Transaction not active

Tags: hibernate, jpa, servlets

This is the source code causing the error:

```
@Override
@Transactional
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public Object queryObject(String query) throws Exception {
    Object o = null;
    EntityTransaction tr = em.getTransaction();

    try {
        if (!tr.isActive()) {
            tr.begin();
        }

        List<Object> objectsList = em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
        if (!objectsList.isEmpty()) {
            o = objectsList.get(0);
        }
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
        em.close();
        tr.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tr.rollback();
        System.out.println("" + e.getMessage());
    }
    return o;
}
```

And this is the instruction where the method is called:

UserAccount userAccount = (UserAccount) accountDao.queryObject("select u.identifier,u.email,u.password from UserAccount as u where identifier=" + account.getIdentifier() + " and  password=" + account.getPassword());

Comment: Please add what error you are getting.

Comment: why would you close the EntityManager before committing its transaction?! If you get an exception you say WHAT LINE IT OCCURS AT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using container managed transactions - you don't need to do this yourself.

Your code can collapse down to:

```
@Override
@Transactional
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public Object queryObject(String query) throws PersistenceException {
    try {
        return em.createQuery(query).getSingleResult();
    } catch (NonUniqueResultException e) {
        // too many results
        return null;
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        // not enough results
        return null;
    }
}
```

**However**

Composing queries like this:

```
"select u.identifier,u.email,u.password from UserAccount as u where identifier=" 
  + account.getIdentifier() + " and password=" + account.getPassword())
```

can lead to [SQL injection attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/).

The JPA [javax.persistence.Query](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html) class has a bunch of `setParameter` methods that you must use to circumvent this.

Therefore it's generally easier to write specific query methods instead of the generic method that you're trying here.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful to me. Using your source code, I finally found the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096856/transaction-not-active-hibernate-jpa) about not active transactions? Why are you manually managing transactions if you are using `@Transactional`?

I'd also like to show you how to better write your dao (look the automatic cast to `UserAccount.class` and the use of parameters to avoid injections):

```
@Stateless
@Transactional
public class UserAccountDao {
    private static final String SELECT_USERACCOUNT_BY_IDENTIFIER_AND_PASSWORD = "select ua from UserAccount ua where ua.identifier = :identifier and ua.password = :password";

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public UserAccount selectUserAccountByIdentifierAndPAssword(final String identifier, final String password) {
        List<UserAccount> userAccounts = em.createQuery(SELECT_USERACCOUNT_BY_IDENTIFIER_AND_PASSWORD, UserAccount.class)
            .setParameter("identifier", identifier)
            .setParameter("password", password)
            .getResultList();
        return userAccounts == null || userAccounts.isEmpty() ? null : userAccounts.get(0);
    }
}
```

You can use it with:

```
UserAccount userAccount = uadao.selectUserAccountByIdentifierAndPAssword(account.getIdentifier(), account.getPassword());
if (userAccount == null) {
    // manage error
}
```

This code is hand written so it may contain some errors.