# Remove all contents of a table from time to time using Java JPA (EclipseLink) MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I really need your help

I need to remove all contents of a table from time to time, I'm using Java + JPA (EclipseLink) + MySQL

I am using the following code below but without success, I have no knowledge whatsoever on JPA

```
public void deleteTableFupfile(){
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<fupfile> query = qb.createQuery(fupfile.class);        
        Root<fupfile> fupfile = query.from(fupfile.class);

        Query q2 = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM fupfile");
        q2.executeUpdate();

    }
```

exceptions:

Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-8029] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [DELETE FROM fupfile], line 1, column 26: invalid navigation expression [fupfile.id], cannot navigate expression [fupfile] of type [java.lang.Class] inside a query.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException.invalidNavigation(JPQLException.java:413)

Comment: Are there any exceptions thrown?

Comment: This code won't compile as case is important in java. `Fupfile` and `fupfile` are different names.

Comment: Hello nailgun, sorry was typo in the code is correct and still does not work, posted above the thrown exception. thank you

Comment: I believe the problem is in the line "DELETE FROM fupfile" but not figured out yet how to solve it

Comment: Andrei I posted the above exception thanks for the help

Comment: For clarity, remove the CriteriaBuilder, CriteriaQuery and Root as you are not using them.  The JPQL query should use the entity name, which defaults to the classname if undefined.  If your class really is 'fupfile' instead of FupFile, show the entity code and the full exception stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Now yes, the below code, it worked perfectly, thank you all for your help!

```
public void deleteTabelaFupfile(){
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();

        Query q2 = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM fupfile e");
        q2.executeUpdate(); 

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

The link below helped me a lot;
[JPA No transaction is currently active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758166/jpa-no-transaction-is-currently-active)