# How to roll back JTA transaction correctly?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jta

What is the **correct** way of rolling back the transaction of a container managed JTA transaction?

I understand this: [EJBException when calling entityManager.getTransaction()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451846/ejbexception-when-calling-entitymanager-gettransaction)
that I can't get the transaction instance.
I read a solution [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/425702/EJB-JEE/java/setRollBackOnly-sessionBean-CMT-JTA) but I'm not sure whether this is correct.

I'm also aware that, if I throw an exception, the transaction will be rolled back.

But my question is: if I want to (must) use a container managed `EntityManager`, what's the correct way of rolling back a transaction inside it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The asnwer on Code Ranch is right, you have to use `SessionContext`

```
@Resource
private SessionContext ctx;

//and then in method
if(fail) {
    ctx.setRollBackOnly(); 
}
```

See also this [article](http://www.developerscrappad.com/547/java/java-ee/ejb3-x-jpa-when-to-use-rollback-and-setrollbackonly/).