# JPA - Container Managed Persistence doesn't persist entity -JTA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, persistence, jta

I m trying to integrate Spring and JSF i stuck on persisting  object. I dont want to handle transaction  (begin - commit etc)

After some googling i could find an answer give what  i need [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451846/ejbexception-when-calling-entitymanager-gettransaction#answer-6452148)

I'm using  eclipselink as ORM and Oracle 11g database and Glassfish server 3.1 with maven. 
I prefered  annotation for Spring configuration. I use

```
@Transactional
@Service
```

annotations in related class. 
My `persistence.xml` name is **E_DefterManagementPU**     and my transaction-type  is JTA.
Here is my code to persist **efaFunctions**

```
public EntityManager entityManager;

@Inject
public void setEntityManager() {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.
            createEntityManagerFactory("E_DefterManagementPU");
    this.entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
}    

public void create(EfaFunctions efaFunctions) {              
    entityManager.persist(efaFunctions);  
}
```

Entity manager is not null and i can see **assign sequence to the object ** log on glassfish but he other logs are  not generated but if i write the code below whic invisible parts are same with aboe code block ;

```
public void create(EfaFunctions efaFunctions) {       
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(efaFunctions);  
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

it persists the object. 
This works but i dont want to handle **begin()**   **commit()** parts and according resources with JTA Container Managed Persistence should do this instead of me. Can any body tell me where i m wrong  Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you doing this in the context of an EJB (Enterprise Java Bean)?  If not, there are no container managed transactions, and you must manage the transaction in code (which really is not that bad).

Comment: Thanks Bailey,actually i dont use EJB i'm trying to this service layer of my web project.My Beans are above and they are JSF ManagedBeans.Without any knowledge on EJB i hope i could define properly.

Comment: If there is no container manager how spring can handle the transaction without managing it.Sorry for my uneducated questions but  I have a spring project and its running with the code below 
`protected Class<T> entityClass;

   @PersistenceContext

   protected EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
   public T create(T t) {
      this.entityManager.persist(t);
      return t;
   }`

Comment: The container managed transactions are part of the EJB specification.  If you are not using EJB, this feature simply is not available, and you will be much happier doing something that works with "messy" code, than looking at "clean" codes which does not work.

Comment: Thanks i gues it is an answer for the last comments too

Comment: I added an answer so I could show the block of code more easily, and to maybe help someone that sees this question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSF managed beans there are **no implicit transactions**.  The only way to avoid managing the transactions manually would be to create an EJB in the application server, and have the JSF managed bean call it to persist data.  You are using GlassFish, so using EJB would be possible... but it is definitely a new level of complexity.  A great way to handle persistence transactions is to have a try-catch block template like this:

```
    EntityManager em = ... //However you get an em.
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        // ...  Put your persistence code here.

        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        throw ex;
    }finally {
        em.close();
    }
```

It is not as clean looking as the super slick CDI and automatic transactions, but it will handle transactions properly, and ensure data integrity.

Comment: Thanks !!! I got it .But I m using some Spring and some JSF in my project .
I referenced this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/).Can this change the situation?Can i use with this structure ?

Comment: The try-catch-finally block will work great in any programming context that you have an `EntityManager`.  If you are using Spring to inject the `EntityManager` you can safely omit the `finally {em.close();}` bit, because Spring does this for you.

Comment: i switched  using JSF and EJB for my prject and it goes well . ContainerManagedPersistence make +Spring  unnecessary for my project.