# JPA EntityTransaction Throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, jpa, insert

Forgive me for not including something, I'm new here.
here is the console info

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.rollback(EntityTransactionImpl.java:176)
    music.data.ProductDB.insertProduct(ProductDB.java:73)
    music.admin.ProductAdminController.updateProduct(ProductAdminController.java:123)
    music.admin.ProductAdminController.doGet(ProductAdminController.java:37)
    music.admin.ProductAdminController.doPost(ProductAdminController.java:50)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

[Debug IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTQrx.png)

If you look at the above image, you see that right before the call to commit(); the transaction  is verymuch so active. the rest of the files that are involved are here:
ProductDB.java (Database managing class)

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package music.data;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import music.business.Product;

/**
 *
 * @author Harley
 */
public class ProductDB {

    public static List<Product> selectProducts() {
        List<Product> products;
        DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
        EntityManager em = util.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
        String JPQL = "SELECT p FROM Product p";
        TypedQuery<Product> q = em.createQuery(JPQL, Product.class);
        products = q.getResultList();
        if (products.isEmpty()) {
            products = null;
        }
        em.close();
        return products;
    }

    public static Product selectProduct(String productCode) {
        DBUtil u = new DBUtil();
        EntityManager em = u.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
        String JPQL = "Select p from Product p "
                + "where p.code = :code";
        TypedQuery<Product> q = em.createQuery(JPQL, Product.class);
        q.setParameter("code", productCode);
        try {
            Product p = q.getSingleResult();
            return p;
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public static boolean exists(String productCode) {
        Product p = selectProduct(productCode);
        if (p != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void insertProduct(Product p) {
        DBUtil u = new DBUtil();
        EntityManager em = u.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
        trans.begin();
        try {
            em.persist(p);
            trans.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            trans.rollback();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public static void updateProduct(Product p) {
        DBUtil u = new DBUtil();
        EntityManager em = u.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
        trans.begin();
        try {
            em.merge(p);
            trans.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            trans.rollback();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public static void deleteProduct(Product p) {
        DBUtil u = new DBUtil();
        EntityManager em = u.getEmFactory().createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
        trans.begin();
        try {
            em.remove(em.merge(p));
            trans.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            trans.rollback();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    private static class DBUtil {

        private final EntityManagerFactory emf;

        public DBUtil() {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("productMaintenancePU");
        }

        public EntityManagerFactory getEmFactory() {
            return emf;
        }
    }
}
```

The jsp file that i use to add/update entries is here:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@include file="includes/header.jsp" %>
<h1>Product</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${product != null}">
            <label>Code:</label>
            <input name="productCode" class="smallText" type="text" value=
                   <c:out value="${product.getCode()}"/>><br/>
            <label>Description:</label>
            <input name="description" class="bigText" type="text" value="${product.getDescription()}"><br/>
            <label>Price:</label>
            <input name="price" class="smallText" type="text" value=
                   <c:out value="${product.getPrice()}"/>><br/>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <label>Code:</label>
            <input name="productCode" class="smallText" type="text"/><br/>
            <label>Description:</label>
            <input name="description" class="bigText" type="text"/><br/>
            <label>Price:</label>
            <input name="price" class="smallText" type="text"/><br/>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
            <label>&nbsp;</label>
            <button type="submit" name="action" value="updateProduct">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="productMaintenancePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/music_jpa?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="sesame"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The Servlet

```
package music.admin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import music.business.Product;
import music.data.ProductDB;

public class ProductAdminController extends HttpServlet {

    /* Comment this method out when using this class with a database
     * instead of a text file.
     */

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        // get current action
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if (action == null) {
            action = "displayProducts";  // default action
        }

        // perform action and set URL to appropriate page
        String url = "/index.jsp";
        if (action.equals("displayProduct")) {
            url = displayProduct(request, response);
        } else if (action.equals("addProduct")) {
            url = "/product.jsp";
        } else if (action.equals("deleteProduct")) {
            url = deleteProduct(request, response);
        } else if (action.equals("updateProduct")) {
            url = updateProduct(request, response);
        } else {
            url = displayProducts(request, response);
        }
        getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher(url)
                .forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        doGet(request, response);
    }

    private String displayProducts(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        List<Product> products = ProductDB.selectProducts();
        request.setAttribute("products", products);
        return "/products.jsp";
    }

    private String displayProduct(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        String productCode = request.getParameter("productCode");
        Product product;
        if (productCode == null || productCode.isEmpty()) {
            product = new Product();
        } else {
            product = ProductDB.selectProduct(productCode);
        }

        request.setAttribute("product", product);
        return "/product.jsp";
    }

    private String addProduct(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        return "/product.jsp";
    }

    private String updateProduct(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        String productCode = (String) request.getParameter("productCode");
        String description = (String) request.getParameter("description");
        String priceString = (String) request.getParameter("price");

        double price;
        try {
            price = Double.parseDouble(priceString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            price = 0;
        }

        Product product = (Product) request.getAttribute("product");
        if (product == null) {
            product = new Product();
        }
        product.setCode(productCode);
        product.setDescription(description);
        product.setPrice(price);
        request.setAttribute("product", product);

        String message = "";
        if (product.getPrice() <= 0) {
            message = "You must enter a positive number for the price without "
                    + "any currency symbols.";
        }
        if (product.getDescription().length() == 0) {
            message = "You must enter a description for the product.";
        }
        if (product.getCode().length() == 0) {
            message = "You must enter a code for the product.";
        }
        request.setAttribute("message", message);

        String url;
        if (message.isEmpty()) {
            if (ProductDB.selectProduct(product.getCode()) != null) {
                ProductDB.updateProduct(product);
            } else {
                ProductDB.insertProduct(product);
            }
            url = displayProducts(request, response);
        } else {
            url = "/product.jsp";
        }
        return url;
    }

    private String deleteProduct(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        String productCode = request.getParameter("productCode");
        Product product = ProductDB.selectProduct(productCode);
        request.setAttribute("product", product);

        String url;
        String yesButton = request.getParameter("yesButton");
        if (yesButton != null) {
            ProductDB.deleteProduct(product);
            url = displayProducts(request, response);
        } else {
            url = "/confirm_product_delete.jsp";
        }
        return url;
    }    
}
```

JPA Entity: product

```
package music.business;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String code;
    private String description;
    private double price;

    public Product() {
        code = "";
        description = "";
        price = 0;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getPriceNumberFormat() {
        NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        number.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        if (price == 0) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return number.format(price);
        }
    }

    public String getPriceCurrencyFormat() {
        NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        return currency.format(price);
    }
}
```

products.jsp(displays all entries)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@include file="includes/header.jsp" %>
<h1>Products</h1>
<table>
    <col width='80'><col width='500'><col width='80'><col width='50'><col width='100'>
    <tr>
        <th class="alignl">Code</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th class="alignr">Price</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${products}">
        <tr>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <td><input name="productCode" hidden type="text" value="${item.getCode()}"/>${item.getCode()}</td>
            <td>${item.getDescription()}</td>
            <td class="alignr">${item.getPriceCurrencyFormat()}</td>
            <td><button name="action" value="displayProduct" type="submit">Edit</button></td>
            <td><button name = "action" value="deleteProduct" type="submit">Delete</button></td>
        </form>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
<form method="post" action="ProductMaint3">
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="addProduct">Add Product</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Functionally, the only issue occurs when i try to insert a new entry into the database... delete and update work. pls let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: where is product.jsp??

Comment: its the second block of code. the jsp file used for updating or adding a product to the DB

Comment: the method updateProduct is called no matter what. within that method,  insertProduct is called if there are no errors with input and if the product code (primaryKey) entered doesn't refer to an existing product

Comment: addProduct is only refered to in another jsp, ill include that.

Comment: first idea before any    trans.rollback(); or commit   try to check if transaction is still active by using getTransaction().isActive() if true then rollback or comit

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451846/ejbexception-when-calling-entitymanager-gettransaction)

Comment: [and this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758166/jpa-no-transaction-is-currently-active)

Comment: it is active. i just added if trans.isActive() before the call to commit. also the img i included shows the debug values for trans, one of which is active = true.

Comment: i found this in the log...    javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'PRODUCTID' doesn't have a default value
Error Code: 1364
Call: INSERT INTO PRODUCT (CODE, DESCRIPTION, PRICE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
 bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(music.business.Product@b271939) I am also using resource_local... I dont see an answer there

Comment: for my jpa project I use [this](https://jeddict.github.io/page.html?l=tutorial/JavaEE_MVC) that may help you avoid ambiguous errors

Answer (score 0):

There was an additional column in the product table named PRODUCTID. this was the primary key AND a foreign key. I'm still new to sql, so i don't know how to handle or work with foreign keys... additionally, this column is NOT required to allow the program to work. this table was given to me by my instructor... so I'll have to talk to her. Answer: removing the column PRODUCTID and i no longer received an error. works perfectly.